# Very complicated SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using MySql and supposed to create a very complicated report that shows events state.

For example:

```
event_id   |  state        |  create_time
----------------------------------------------------
1          |    PENDING    | 2019-04-21 12:55:59.312
1          |   COMPLETED   | 2019-04-21 12:55:59.339
2          |   PENDING     | 2019-04-21 11:40:21.699
3          |   PENDING     | 2019-04-21 11:40:21.699
3          |   FAILED      | 2019-04-21 11:40:21.600
3          |   COMPLETED   | 2019-04-21 11:40:21.578
```

I need to select rows according to states preferences:

- FAILED + COMPLETED + PENDING  ->  FAILED
- COMPLETED + PENDING -> COMPLETED
- PENDING alone -> PENDING

This should be paginated using OFFSET and SIZE.

Each event will be shown once.

expected result:

```
event_id   |  state        |  create_time
----------------------------------------------------
1          |   COMPLETED   | 2019-04-21 12:55:59.339
2          |   PENDING     | 2019-04-21 11:40:21.699
3          |   FAILED      | 2019-04-21 11:40:21.600
```

---

How can I do this in a single SQL query.

Regards,
Ido

Comment: Please show the results that you want.  I have no idea what you mean by "FAILED + COMPLETED + PENDING -> FAILED", for instance.

Comment: Added expected result

Comment: Is your table structure set in stone? This would be much easier to use if you had an integer FK to another table that stored dictionary records for each state and their priority instead of the state name on this table.

Comment: No.. simple table.  PK is event_id and state

Comment: i posted a answer i think it should work.

Comment: As I understand it FAILED is #1 priority, COMPLETED is #2 and PENDING is #3. If you had a separate column indicating the states as numbers this would be an easy task. If you can create the column, it would be an easy task also to add state numbers using `UPDATE` query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do aggregation with `coalesce()` :

```
select event_id,
       coalesce(max(case when state = 'FAILED' then 'FAILED' end),
                max(case when state = 'COMPLETED' then 'COMPLETED' end),
                'PENDING'     
               )
from table t
group by event_id;
```

Answer (score 3):

I suspect you want aggregation with some conditional logic, like this:

```
select event_id,
       (case when sum(state = 'FAILED') > 0 then 'FAILED'
             when sum(state = 'COMPLETED') > 0 then 'COMPLETED'
             when sum(state = 'PENDING') > 0 then 'PENDING'
        end) as new_state
from t
group by event_id;
```

Comment: Oh... This does not work,
COMPLETED is always prefered - probably due to A,B,C.  even if I order by create_time

Comment: If COMPLETED should be prioritized first then you need to change your question. Your question shows FAILED taking priority over the COMPLETED state... `FAILED + COMPLETED + PENDING -> FAILED`

Comment: I prefer FAILED... But the query prefers completed!

Answer (score 1):

A other option is handling those states preferences as bitmasks.

**Note**
This method assumes that there are no duplicated stats for a event_id.

**Query**

```
SELECT 
 t.*
FROM (

SELECT 
   t.event_id
 , SUM(bitmask_table.bitmask) AS total_bitmask
FROM (
  SELECT
    DISTINCT 
       state
     , CASE 
        WHEN state = 'PENDING'
        THEN 2

        WHEN state = 'COMPLETED'
        THEN 4

        WHEN state = 'FAILED'
        THEN 8
       END AS bitmask
  FROM
   t 
) AS bitmask_table
INNER JOIN 
 t
ON
 t.state = bitmask_table.state
GROUP BY 
 t.event_id

) AS group_bitmasked
INNER JOIN 
 t
ON
  group_bitmasked.event_id = t.event_id
AND
 t.state = CASE
    WHEN group_bitmasked.total_bitmask & 8 AND group_bitmasked.total_bitmask & 4 AND  group_bitmasked.total_bitmask & 2
    THEN 'FAILED'

    WHEN group_bitmasked.total_bitmask & 4 AND group_bitmasked.total_bitmask & 2
    THEN 'COMPLETED'  

    WHEN group_bitmasked.total_bitmask & 2
    THEN 'PENDING'      
   END
```

**Result**

```
| event_id | state     | create_time             |
| -------- | --------- | ----------------------- |
| 1        | COMPLETED | 2019-04-21 12:55:59.339 |
| 2        | PENDING   | 2019-04-21 11:40:21.699 |
| 3        | FAILED    | 2019-04-21 11:40:21.600 |
```

see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9B4q6Jw1aZeuoxf7gLqkwH/0)

Comment: This is genius.